# How do i convert a Google Sheets formula into an Excel formula

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

A week ago I found help here in creating a formula in Google Sheets. Now the requirements have changed. The new requirement is to create the document as an Excel document. I can't take the formula into Excel like this (in the following you can see the formula):

```
=map( 
  B2:B20, C2:C20, D2:D20, E2:E20, 
  lambda( 
    startDay, startTime, endDay, endTime, 
    if( 
      startDay * startTime * endDay * endTime * (startDay + startTime <= endDay + endTime), 
      let( 
        businessStart, value("7:00"), businessEnd, value("15:00"), 
        pushToNextDay, startDay + (startTime > businessEnd), 
        startDayOfWeek, weekday(pushToNextDay, 2), 
        effectiveStartDay, switch(startDayOfWeek, 6, pushToNextDay + 2, 7, pushToNextDay + 1, pushToNextDay), 
        startOutsideBusinessHours, or(startTime > businessEnd, startTime < businessStart, startDayOfWeek > 5), 
        effectiveStartTime, if(startOutsideBusinessHours, businessStart, startTime), 
        daysBetween, max(0, networkdays(effectiveStartDay, endDay) - 2), 
        hoursBetween, daysBetween * (businessEnd - businessStart), 
        hoursStartDay, businessEnd - effectiveStartTime, 
        hoursEndDay, endTime - businessStart, 
        if( 
          effectiveStartDay = endDay, 
          endTime - effectiveStartTime, 
          hoursStartDay + hoursEndDay + hoursBetween 
        ) 
      ), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This formula was created to calculate the time difference between incoming emails to replies. So the response time has to be determined. The weekends that fall between the arrival and response of the emails have to be subtracted. In addition, the daily working time (7 am - 3 pm) must be taken into account.

the result of the formula can be seen in column F.

[image]

I know this forum is more about Google Sheets. **Since I already got the Google Sheets formula in this forum, how can I convert it to Excel?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Tripping on IFERROR

The formula works in Excel with the exception of the [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) function:
`IFERROR(value, value_if_error)`

In [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611), **value_if_error** is a **required** field.

In your Excel formula, if you change `IFERROR(1/0)` to `IFERROR(1/0,"")` your formula will work.

In [Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304), **value_if_error** is an optional field.  If omitted, **value_if_error** returns a blank. It is a common convention in Sheets to replace `IFERROR(1/0,"")` by `IFERROR(1/0)` because the latter returns a truly blank cell.

Example: `COUNTA("")=1`
               `COUNTA(IFERROR(1/0))=0`